# DIsplay Block content after certain time delay

Tags: views, blocks

I need to show the block content to users after certain delay of page load . Initially the user will see only the article , but after certain time the block content will be revealed . Can it be done ? any pointer is appreciated .

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: check this https://www.drupal.org/node/320621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a block and set it to the region and page you'd like it to appear at
- Use CSS to hide the contents of the block
- Use JavaScript to override the hiding and display at a specific interval

The CSS would look something like this:

```
.block-DELTA {
  display: hidden;
}
```

And then just use JavaScript to display the block [after a specified interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval).  You could also [add some animation to your CSS property to make it fade in](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/).  (That's just one example tutorial on animating, google and you'll find hundreds more)

You can add the CSS and JavaScript to the block in a number of ways.  The quickest and dirtiest is in the block content itself.  I'd strongly recommend storing any code in either a module or theme.  See [`drupal_add_css()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) and [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) for more information on implementing.